# How to add enter/exit Java actions to a custom flowchart block

Tags: java, anylogic

I am building a custom flowchart block in my AnyLogic model and was looking for a way to add "on Enter" and "on Exit" actions to my custom block. I can write the codes inside the block but it makes it easier and cleaner to have the Java actions added to custom block and write the code in one level higher.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an Action parameter.  You can set it to take parameters, if you would like.  I almost always allow for passing in an agent, but sometimes I make it more specific to a certain class type, depending on the project.

[image]

Once you have that set up, when you drag you custom agent on to the screen, you will see that as an option to pass in a function or a few lines of code.

The last piece is then within your custom agent, you need to call "onEnterAction" at the appropriate time.  If you use an enter block, call it then.  If you are connecting via ports, you may need to place that on the first block the agent gets to after coming in via the port.